# Link in example newsletter leads to dead YouTube video

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter, link-rot

When visiting an SE community you are currently not a part of, you may see something like this:

[image]

Upon clicking the "example newsletter" link you can scroll all the way to the bottom to find these three links:

- [Unsubscribe from this newsletter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q44qwyHlMfk)
- [subscriptions page on stackexchange.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY)
- [unsubscribe from all stackexchange.com emails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6LzEbuI7e8)

The first one links to a dead YouTube video. I want to know what I am missing out on, so make sure it links to a same video, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up! The link is fixed now. Enjoy. :)

Comment: This is the best link out of the three, 10/10

Comment: Still dead for me...